Telegraf cannot reach URL
I wrote a small telegraf.conf. When I put it in a docker compose it works. When I put it in my Kubernetes CLuster it does not.
The logs say: [inputs.http] Error in plugin: [url=https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=10838,10840]: Get "https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=10838,10840": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
I tried with http://google.de as altenrative url (for debugging) with the same result.
[agent]   interval = "10s"   round_interval = true   metric_batch_size
= 1000   metric_buffer_limit = 10000   collection_jitter = "0s"   flush_interval = "10s"   flush_jitter = "0s"   precision = ""   debug
= false   quiet = false   logfile = ""   hostname = ""   omit_hostname = false

[[inputs.http]]   ## URL zur GET-Anfrage   urls = [
    "https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=10838,10840" ]   method = "GET"   interval = "10s"   response_timeout = "5s"   data_format = "json"

[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]   ## InfluxDB 2.0 URL   urls = ["http://influxdb-nfluxdb2.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:8086"]   organization = "influxdata"   bucket = "default"   token = "securetoken"

I expected the config to work both with docker compose and within Kubernetes(K3s).
